# How do I test for a lookup list item, and add it if it is missing, in SharePoint 2007 via C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

I am having trouble **when I attempt to add a value to a lookup column**.

I am using SharePoint 2007 and the app has to run in .NET 2.0.  The language is C#.  **Some lookup columns will allow multiple values.**

## Question

Using C#, how do I do #'s 2-4 of the following:

1. Attempt to add a list item to a SP list.
2. For any lookup columns, check the SP List they are referencing to see if that list contains the value I am attempting to add.
3. If the value DOES NOT exist in the lookup list, add it.
4. Associate the newly added lookup value to the list item I was originally trying to add.

I have been googling this, of course, but am still stuck.  Here is some code from Microsoft which is a start, but it is still not getting me going (not commented and not intuitive to me):

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPList customerList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Contoso Customers");
                    SPList orderList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Contoso Orders");

                    if (customerList != null && orderList != null)
                    {
                        SPListItemCollection customers = customerList.Items;
                        SPListItemCollection orders = orderList.Items;

                        string fieldName = "CustIDLookup";
                        if (!orderList.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName))
                            return;
                        
                        SPField lookupFld = orderList.Fields.GetField(fieldName);

                        foreach (SPListItem customer in customers)
                        {
                            SPListItem order = orders.Add();
                            order[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "Thank you!";
                            order.Update();

                            SPFieldLookupValue value = new SPFieldLookupValue(customer.ID, customer.ID.ToString());
                            order[lookupFld.Id] = value.ToString();
                            order.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even with Microsoft's examples, I can't get any real traction in figuring out how to actually do this.

Your help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to add, in case I get the "StackOverflow is not a rent-a-coder" comments: I am having to develop on a remotely connected SP server and, thanks to some kind of plugin that the IT department is using, I can't debug.  So this is like coding blindfolded.  Again--your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
//untested pseudocode - hope this points you in the right direction

SPList lookupItems = ... // add code here
SPList list = ... // add code here
string lookupFieldName = "LookupValue"; // change to the appropriate value

foreach(SPListItem item in list.Items)
{ 
    string value = (string)item[lookupFieldName];
    if(value.Contains("#")) // value containing hash is most likely a lookup value already
    {
         // use SPFieldLookupValue to get actual value
         SPFieldLookupValue currentValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(value);
         value = currentValue.LookupValue;
    }

    // Get the list item (you will need this to find out its id value)
    SPListItem lookupItem = GetLookupListItem(lookupList, value);
    if(lookupItem == null)
    {
        //If it doesn't exist, create it
        lookupItem = AddNewLookupItem(lookupList, value);
        SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue = new      SPFieldLookupValue(lookupItem.ID,value));
        item["LookupValue"] = lookupValue.ToString();
        item.Update();
    }
}
SPListItem GetLookupListItem(SPList lookupList, string value)
{
    // iterate through list to find item
    // use a list query if the list is too big for this to perform well (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms456030.aspx)
    foreach(SPListItem item in lookupList)
    {
        string itemValue = (string)item[0]; // assuming lookup list has one field of type string containing lookup value
        if(value == itemValue)
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

SPListItem AddLookupListItem(SPList list, string value)
{
    SPListItem newItem = list.Add();
    newItem[0] = value;// assuming lookup list has one field of type string containing lookup value
    newItem.Update();
}
```